# Javascript RegExp using .test()

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I need to validate that the user is text only and I want to use a regexp.
Something like:
if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(user))
{ show invalid message }

this particular solution wont work, I appreciate the help, im pretty new in JS.

Comment: Why are you showing an invalid username message for a valid username?

Comment: My idea is to show an invalid message if the person that is trying to access put special characters or spaces in the text field. Is it a bad idea to do it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **inverted boolean** (`!`) before the regex,

```
if(!/^[a-z]+$/i.test(user)){ error }
```

i.e:

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
  if(!/^[a-z]+$/i.test(this.value))
  { 
    alert("Only [A-Za-z] characters are allowed");
    this.value= this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/i,"");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much, I spent hours looking for a solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to just say `if (/[^a-z]/i.test(value))`.

Comment: Sure it is...I overlook that. Tks!